# BeautifulSoup responses - Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client

Tags: python, postgresql, web-scraping

The script should find the addresses of subpages with articles and collect the necessary data from them. The data should go to the database. 
Data should be collected by processing HTML documents.

exactly what it should: 1. 
find the 10 most common words with their numbers. 2. find 
The 10 most common words with their numbers per author. 3. 
posts authors with their name

I'm not sure the rest of the code works well but for now I'm getting the following error:
[image: error]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import psycopg2 as pg2
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import psycopg2

url = 'https://teonite.com/blog/page/{}/index.html'
all_links = []

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://teonite.com/blog/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
    all_links.append(article_links)
    num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.page-number').text.split('/')[1])

    for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        r = s.get(url.format(page))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
        all_links.append(article_links)

    all_links = [item for i in all_links for item in i]

    d = webdriver.Chrome()

    for article in all_links:
        d.get(article)
        soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
        [t.extract() for t in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]
        visible_text = soup.getText()

        try:
            print(soup.select_one('.post-title').text)
        except:
            print(article)
            print(soup.select_one('h1').text)
            break

    # nie moj !!!!!!

    # 2.2. Post contents
    contents = []
    for article_links in all_links:
        soup = bs((article), 'html.parser')
        content = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'post-content'})
        contents.append(content)

    # 2.1. Authors

    authors = []
    for article in all_links:
        soup = bs(article, 'html.parser')
        author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})
        authors.append(author)

    # POSTGRESQL CONNECTION
    # 1. Connect to local database using psycopg2

    import psycopg2

    hostname = 'balarama.db.elephantsql.com'
    username = 'yagoiucf'
    password = 'jxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    database = 'yagoiucf'

    conn = psycopg2.connect(host='balarama.db.elephantsql.com', user='yagoiucf',
                            password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', dbname='yagoiucf')
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems:

look at this part of your code

```
# 2.2. Post contents
contents = []
for article_links in all_links:
    soup = bs((article), 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'post-content'})
    contents.append(content)


# 2.1. Authors

authors = []
for article in all_links:
    soup = bs(article, 'html.parser')
    author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})
    authors.append(author)
```

in the first loop you have `article_links`, but then you pass `article` to `BeautifulSoup`. First of all `article` is an artefact from a previous loop and represent an url. I guess you actually want to pass `article_links` instead.

Second, in the code above that snippet you use selenium to retrieve the page source.

```
d = webdriver.Chrome()

for article in all_links:
    d.get(article)
    soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
```

You need to do the same again (or use requests if you can)

Comment: still the same. Could you show me exactly what to do? 
these are completely new things for me ..